# git terminal minimal display

Tags: git

When working with git in terminal, anytime I do a git command I always get usage, Generic options, etc. Is there a command I can run when I run git that will only show what I need to see and not the usage information? This will help me to visually see more. Thank you.

Here is an example

```
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   css/
#   index.html
#   js/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
usage: git branch [options] [-r | -a] [--merged | --no-merged]
or: git branch [options] [-l] [-f] <branchname> [<start-point>]
or: git branch [options] [-r] (-d | -D) <branchname>
or: git branch [options] (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>

Generic options
-v, --verbose         show hash and subject, give twice for upstream branch
-t, --track           set up tracking mode (see git-pull(1))
--set-upstream        change upstream info
--color[=<when>]      use colored output
-r                    act on remote-tracking branches
--contains <commit>   print only branches that contain the commit
--abbrev[=<n>]        use <n> digits to display SHA-1s

Specific git-branch actions:
-a                    list both remote-tracking and local branches
-d                    delete fully merged branch
-D                    delete branch (even if not merged)
-m                    move/rename a branch and its reflog
-M                    move/rename a branch, even if target exists
-l                    create the branch's reflog
-f, --force           force creation (when already exists)
--no-merged <commit>  print only not merged branches
--merged <commit>     print only merged branches
```

What I am asking here is if there is short command that would help clear up some real estate when typing commands so the Generic options and Specific git-branch actions would not always appear.

**Edit with output from git config --get-regexp "alias"**

```
alias.st status
alias.ci commit
alias.co checkout
alias.br branch
alias.l log --graph --pretty=format':%C(yellow)%h%Cblue%d%Creset %s %C(white) %an,    %ar%Creset'
alias.lol log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate
alias.unstage reset HEAD
alias.staged diff --cached
alias.unstaged diff
alias.current-branch !git symbolic-ref -q HEAD | sed -e 's|^refs/heads/||'
alias.track checkout -t

$ ps | grep $$
3406 ttys000    0:00.09 -bash
3492 ttys000    0:00.00 grep 3406
```

Comment: You're seeing this any time you do a git command? Sounds like a broken alias or something. Can you post an example?

Comment: @AbeVoelker - I posted the output above that I would like to have the option of hiding while running commands in the terminal.

Comment: What was the command you typed to get that? It looks like incorrect usage of `git branch`.  This could be from a bad system alias or git alias.  Please post output of these commands: `alias` and `git config --get-regexp "alias.*"`

Comment: @AbeVoelker - I have edited the above with the output. Please let me know if you see something here that will help me so that I don't see all of this when working on terminal. Even when I change to a folder that has a repository I get all of this information which I prefer to not have to take up my whole terminal all of the time.

Comment: If this happens even without doing git commands, then it's probably a custom prompt issue. Are you using something like oh-my-zsh?  Please post the output of `ps | grep $$` and any files that match this pattern from your home directory: `~/.*profile` and `~/.*rc`

Comment: @AbeVoelker - I have aded the information above from which I have not a clue about what this is telling me but my hopes are that it tells you something. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Looks like you're using bash. Could you post your `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, and `~/.bashrc` files?

Comment: More importantly, could you post the output of `echo $PS1` ?

Comment: Or it is something like: function git () { /bin/git %@; /bin/git help %1 }

Answer (score 3):

`git status --short` (or `git status -s`) will show a shorter status, similar to svn's status display.

Comment: Yes this does but my terminal still shows the options for usage, Generic options, and Specific git-branch actions.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, can you edit the question above to specify what you're seeing when, please? Something like "when I type `git whatever` I see `long useless thing`"